# How does this differential equation's solutions embedded in an exponential-exponential coordinate plane change the form of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponentiation, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

$u=\log(x)$ and $v=\log(y)\implies uv=k.$ $uv=k$ satisfies an algebraic differential equation. $X=(x,-y)$ is a vector field with integral curves $uv=k$ in $u-v$ coordinates. A differential equation is $(xy(x))'=0$ which gives solutions $y(x)=k/x.$

Now $\log(x)\log(y)=k$ satisfies the vector field $Y=(x\log(x),-y\log(y)).$ But I can't find the differential equation in this case.

What needs to be done is to map the solution space of $(xy(x))'=0$ to an exponential-exponential coordinate plane and then reconstruct the differential equation. How do you do this exactly?

How does this differential equation embedded in an exponential-exponential coordinate plane change it's form?

I think it will make things more complicated.

Are there any known mathematical problems that are *easier* to solve in an exponential-exponential coordinate space? Is there a fundamental reason why they seem to be more difficult?

Comment: if you write $X=e^x, Y(X)=e^{y(x)}$, then$\frac{d(f\circ X)}{dx} = X\frac{df}{dX}\circ X$ by chain rule, so $\frac d{dx}(xy)= 0$ rewrites to $ X\frac{d}{dX} (\log X \log Y) = 0$, and since $X>0$ we can just write $\frac{d}{dX} (\log X \log Y) = 0$? the function $y(x)=k/x$ becomes $Y(X) = e^{k/x} = e^{k/\log X}$, and you can check that for this choice of $Y$, $\frac{d}{dX} (\log X \log Y) = \frac d{dx} k = 0$. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: No this is good I understand now

Comment: OK, unfortunately it doesn't involve $x\log x$ so I wasn't sure if you wanted something else